# Does an Alarm clock 吵醒 or 叫醒？

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to figure out whether an alarm clock 吵醒我， or 叫醒我。 
I'd like to say the sentence 
my alarm clock woke me up at 5:30 today
my translation so far is
今天早上五点半， 我手机的闹钟叫醒了我。 
Can 叫醒 be done by inanimate objects? Is this construction used in chinese?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, that is fine; it is quite common to use `叫醒` with alarms.

In fact you can use both `吵醒` and `叫醒` here, although there's a small difference in connotations. It isn't a very strong distinction though, so you needn't be overly concerned.

Anyway, `叫醒` normally means the action was **intended** to wake you. In contrast `吵醒` carries the sense that being woken up is **unplanned** or unwanted, i.e. some *noise* woke you (implying you aren't happy about it). For example, if *your neighbours'* alarm woke you, you'd normally use `吵醒`. If the hotel's *morning call* woke you, that's normally `叫醒`.

Comment: Great explanation.

Comment: Would this be a better translation of the entire sentence:  今天早上五点半我被手机闹钟叫醒了。 ?  IE use 被 to say I was woken BY the alarm?

Comment: @DanielHoward yes, that flows better imho

Answer (score 5):

Is depend how you what to tell others on the clock.
If you set the alarm and you like to tell your friend about it, and you mentioned

I need alarm to wake me up then use '叫醒'
You not intend to wake up but someone accidentally turn on alarm for you then you use '吵醒'

So

'叫醒' use when you need someone to wake you

'吵醒' use it when you don't intend wake up but someone/something disturb your sleep.